# filebeat to kafka : Failed to connect to broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2, filebeat

Im new in apache environment and currently im trying to send log data from filebeat producer to kafka broker.

### environment :

1. kafka 2.11 (installed via ambari)
2. filebeat 7.4.2 (windows)

I tried to send logs from filebeat into ambari, I've started kafka servers and created the topic named "test" and it was listed on --list. Im pretty confused about kafka broker's port. In some tutorials i saw they were using 9092 instead 2181. So now ,what port i should use to send logs from filebeat?

### here is my filebeat.conf

```
filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      paths:
       - C:/Users/A/Desktop/DATA/mailbox3.csv
output.kafka:
  hosts: ["x.x.x.x:9092"]
  topic: "test"
  partition.round_robin:
    reachable_only: false
  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 1000000
```

### result

```
2020-06-10T09:00:32.214+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Failed to connect to broker x.x.x.x:9092: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:32.214+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata got error from broker -1 while fetching metadata: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:32.215+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
2020-06-10T09:00:32.215+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
2020-06-10T09:00:32.215+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata retrying after 250ms... (3 attempts remaining)

2020-06-10T09:00:32.466+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata fetching metadata for [test] from broker x.x.x.x:9092

2020-06-10T09:00:34.475+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Failed to connect to broker x.x.x.x:9092: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:34.475+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata got error from broker -1 while fetching metadata: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:34.477+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
2020-06-10T09:00:34.477+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
2020-06-10T09:00:34.478+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata retrying after 250ms... (2 attempts remaining)

2020-06-10T09:00:34.729+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata fetching metadata for [test] from broker x.x.x.x:9092

2020-06-10T09:00:36.737+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Failed to connect to broker x.x.x.x:9092: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:36.737+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata got error from broker -1 while fetching metadata: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:36.738+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
2020-06-10T09:00:36.738+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
2020-06-10T09:00:36.738+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata retrying after 250ms... (1 attempts remaining)

2020-06-10T09:00:36.989+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata fetching metadata for [test] from broker x.x.x.x:9092

2020-06-10T09:00:39.002+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Failed to connect to broker x.x.x.x:9092: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:39.002+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata got error from broker -1 while fetching metadata: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9092: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2020-06-10T09:00:39.004+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
2020-06-10T09:00:39.004+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
2020-06-10T09:00:39.004+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata fetching metadata for [test] from broker x.x.x.x:9092
```

it makes me wonder if i really got 9092 port. So i check out server.properties.Some that i concern the most that:

```
port=6667
listeners=PLAINTEXT://x.x.x.x:6667
```

### so then i try again to do the filebeat.conf and change port 9092 to 6667 and here is the result

```
2020-06-10T09:18:01.448+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata fetching metadata for [test] from broker x.x.x.x:6667

2020-06-10T09:18:01.450+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/broker/1001 starting up

2020-06-10T09:18:01.451+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/broker/1001 state change to [open] on test/0

2020-06-10T09:18:01.451+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/leader/test/0 selected broker 1001

2020-06-10T09:18:01.451+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Failed to connect to broker x.x.x.x:6667: dial tcp: lookup x.x.x.x: no such host

2020-06-10T09:18:01.452+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/broker/1001 state change to [closing] because dial tcp: lookup x.x.x.x: no such host

2020-06-10T09:18:01.453+0700    DEBUG   [kafka] kafka/client.go:264     finished kafka batch
2020-06-10T09:18:01.453+0700    DEBUG   [kafka] kafka/client.go:278     Kafka publish failed with: dial tcp: lookup x.x.x.x: no such host
2020-06-10T09:18:01.454+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/leader/test/0 state change to [flushing-3]

2020-06-10T09:18:01.456+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/leader/test/0 state change to [normal]

2020-06-10T09:18:01.456+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/leader/test/0 state change to [retrying-3]

2020-06-10T09:18:01.456+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/leader/test/0 abandoning broker 1001

2020-06-10T09:18:01.456+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 producer/broker/1001 shut down
```

## questions

What happened? Which port should be used? What is the use of each port?

Any respond will be appreciated so much. Thank you

## UPDATE

according this [source](https://kafka.apache.org/07/documentation.html) the right source is 6667 since kafka was installed via ambari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on the port that can be used, it only depends on the availability.
In the first case, as you said, the broker could have been started on 6667 and hence no process was running on 9092.

> 2020-06-10T09:18:01.451+0700    INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Failed to
>   connect to broker x.x.x.x:6667: dial tcp: lookup x.x.x.x: no such host

Next, when you mention `advertised.listeners` property, you should ensure that the IP you mention in the `advertised.listeners` is the IP assigned to that machine. You cannot assign `1.1.1.1:9092` (just to mention some example).

Execute `ifconfig` (linux), `ipconfig` (windows) and see the IP of your machine on the network interface that is accessible from your application machine.
In linux, it will *mostly* be *eth0*

This IP must be accessible from the machine where you are running your application.
So the machine your application is running on should be able to resolve that IP. You may also want to check your network connection between your Kafka broker and the machine you are running your application on.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your respond i appreciate that a lot. I've make sure that producers able to see kafka's hostname by ping them. it seems i have to edit server.properties and add advertised listeners. I've added advertised.listeners=(as the same as listeners default) and i restart it. Then i trerun filebeat. Nothing changes.

Comment: my kafka was installed via ambari. Is there any other way that i can do to add advertised.listeners other than edit server.properties?

Comment: What is the IP of your machine that is pingable from your producer? Did you use the same IP in your `advertised.listeners`?

Comment: yes, but i put hostname as advertised.listeners because listeners have hostname instead of ip. Is IP a must? Thank you

Comment: Not so I think, as long as the hostname is resolvable by your producer application. You must ensure that whatever you give there is what you give in your producer and that it must be resolvable. You can nevertheless try changing it to IP and check.

Comment: [2020-06-10 08:31:35,355] INFO Calculated collector shard hostname.id  based on hostname: hostname.id (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.availability.MetricSinkWriteShardHostnameHashingStrategy)
it keeps show this when i run kafka server. can you please tell men what does it mean? thank you i will try it with ip now

Comment: IT WORKS! i change both listeners (listeners, advertised.listeners) into ip instead of hostname. Now everytime i try to have contact with brokers i have to use ip instead of hostname/localhost/127.0.0.1. Ive tested it with checking what is the inside of topic. Some suggests, $ /bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:6667 --topic test --from-beginning. it doesnt work for me so i change localhost into ip. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad, that it helped you.